# Dojo AMD not loading custom module

Tags: javascript, dojo, requirejs, arcgis, amd

I'm trying to make a web application using the ArcGIS API, Dojo, and Flask. I want to start by making a "file uploads" dialog, which I am trying to define as its own module using the Dojo 1.7 AMD convention (i.e. "define").

Here is my file structure:

```
\static
     home.js
     fileUpload.js
\templates
     home.html
main.py
```

Here is the code for the dialog (copied from one of the Dojo Tutorials). I am basically trying to put all dialog related function (i.e. show and hide) in one module:

```js
define([
    "dijit/registry",
    "dijit/Dialog",
    "dijit/form/Button",
    "dojo/ready",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function (registry) {


    console.log("HELLO WORLD");


    return {
        // Show the dialog
        showDialog: function() {
            registry.byId("uploads").show();
        },

        // Hide the dialog
        hideDialog: function() {
            registry.byId("uploads").hide();
        }
    }

});
```

At the end of "home.js" I try to create and instance of the dialog module:

```
var fu = new fileUpload();
```

Then in my "home.html" file, I define the actual dialog and try to use the "fu" object's variables as event handlers for closing and opening the dialog:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

    <title>morPOP</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.5/esri/css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/home.css">

    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.5/"></script>

    <script src="../static/js/home.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Map -->
    <div id="viewDiv"></div>

    <!-- Upload Button -->
    <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
        <button type="button" id="uploadbtn" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="fu.showDialog()">Upload</button>
    </div>

    <!-- Upload Dialog -->
    <div class ="dijitHidden">
        <div id="uploads" data-dojo-type="dijit/Dialog" data-dojo-props="title:'Upload Files'">
            <p>The following files must be uploaded to run a simulation. File names must match those listed below.</p>
            <p>Acceptable file extensions: .txt or .csv</p>
            <ul>
                <li>Geographic data</li>
                <ul>
                    <li>Age_Dissemination</li>
                </ul>
                <li> Probability Data </li>
                <ul>
                    <li>ageContactDuration_hospital_nurse</li>
                    <li>ageContactDuration_hospitalPatient</li>
                    <li>ageContactNumber_hospital</li>
                </ul>
                <li> ??? </li>
                <ul>
                    <li>Census_Division_Mapping</li>
                </ul>
            </ul>

            <button onclick="fu.hideDialog();">Finish</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

The error that I get in the google Chrome developer console is the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
    at new g (init.js:56)
    at home.js:51
    at Q (init.js:18)
    at init.js:18
    at A (init.js:18)
    at ea (init.js:18)
    at d (init.js:20)
    at HTMLScriptElement.<anonymous> (init.js:23)
```

I'm not sure what "on" property the error is referring to. Does anyone have any ideas? Why can't I declare an instance of my module?

** EDIT ***

I've changed my home.js file to "require" fileUpload.js, but I am now getting the following error when I try to click the "submit" button:

```
(index):24 Uncaught ReferenceError: fu is not defined
  at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):24)
```

Please see the following plunkr for my updated home.js file: https://plnkr.co/edit/9dFVHsFOCji1aE0ZeLRQ?p=preview

Comment: As a wild guess for the `on` question, an event handler `.on"event"=function`

Comment: could you post in a [planker](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) your home.js

Comment: @bRIMOs here you go, thank you so much:

https://plnkr.co/edit/9dFVHsFOCji1aE0ZeLRQ?p=catalogue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using AMD you manage your dependencies by defining things as you have done with `define()` but client of module must import it using `require()` function, [see docs](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/require.html), meanwhile you try to instantiate required module via `new` which is not correct.

To use some module in DOM handler you need extra wrapper e.g. your HTML would make `onclick="whenClicked()"` if you have this function in scope:

```
function whenClicked() {
  require(['fileUpload'], function(fu) {
    fu.showDialog();
  });
}
```

assuming of course that 'fileUpload' is correctly specified AMD module.

**EDIT:** modified version of OP sample on Plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/QFckwndDicGpTfzhGwFC?p=preview

Note `fileUpload.js` module definition changed so that basic alert is displayed:

```
define([
"dijit/registry",
"dijit/Dialog",
"dijit/form/Button",
"dojo/domReady!"
], function (registry) {
  return {
    // Show the dialog
    showDialog: function() {
        //registry.byId("uploads").show();
        alert("this is file upload mock");
    }
  }
});
```

as well as `home.js` hosting definition of `whenClicked`:

```
function whenClicked() {
  require({
    packages: [
      {name: "fileUpload", 
      // location should point to fileUpload.js on your target server
      location: "https://run.plnkr.co/uv2ILkhQpQC2wqRV",
      main: "fileUpload"}
    ]},
    ['fileUpload'], function(fu) {
      console.log("fileupload");
      fu.showDialog();
  });
}
```

Note that showing `location` of module is similar to what bRIMOs said in other answer. My approach configures however location only for this particular code wrapped by require; approach of bRIMOs is global.

Be aware however that Plunker is rebuilding `location` URL each time you reload editor :/ it effectively means tha you fix location prefix, run it fine, reload Plunker page, and it is broken again.

Comment: thanks so much! I've edited my home.js file to import the module using "require", but when I click the "Submit" button in home.html, I get the following error:        

       
    (index):24 Uncaught ReferenceError: fu is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):24)  
     
     
Please see my changed code in this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/9dFVHsFOCji1aE0ZeLRQ?p=catalogue

Comment: Hmm, in linked code your index.html has JS content and script.js is empty :)  On using require() see my edited answer.

Comment: thanks again for your help, I really appreciate it! I updated the plunkr so that all files are present and properly named, and it uses your whenClicked() function. The error I am getting now is: "(index):23 Uncaught ReferenceError: whenClicked is not defined"

Comment: Define it anywere so that html can "see" it, eg. in your home.js where you wanted to place instance of you file upload module which is linked from web page

Comment: I was only able to get it working by placing it in a script tag in home.html. I still get an undefined error if I place it in the body of the home.js function

Comment: OK, one picture instead of thousand words, I remade Plunker for you, see my updated answer once again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to configure the path in dojo config in order to access the fileupload.js file by the AMD loader , In the [dojoConfig doc](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/dojo_config/) there is many type of config ( basURl ,package , paths ...) , below you can see how to make configuration using `packges` , and dojo will load you files using require without any problem

So before loading your arcgis js api  `<script src="url_api_js"></script>` be sur to do the folowing (configuring dojo with `dojoConfig` var)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var dojoConfig = {
       packages: [
           { 
                name: "mypackage", 
                location: location.pathname.replace(/[^\/]+$/, '') +"/static"
           }
       ]
   };
<script>
<script src="url_api_js"></script>
```

and the inside your code use the name of package/name of file as below

```
require(['mypackage/fileUpload'], function(upload) {
    upload.showDialog();
});
```

NB: the location could change , according to the server type , in this exemple the location is like : `{location_name}/static/fileupload.js`

hopefully this would help you .